# How to stop at breakpoints in a dotnet core mvc application in vscodium(using the netcoredbg in Ubuntu)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was able to stop (at breakpoints) with dotnet core console applications using the netcoredbg in Ubuntu. I probably need to configure the launch.json and perhaps tasks.json but dont know how!